# How to read large text file in Amazon SageMaker?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, dataframe, amazon-sagemaker

I want to read multiple text file from s3 bucket which will make up a data frame of 10M records and 900 columns.
But it is taking too long to read data using ml.p3.2xlarge instance. Moreover, I would like to know if there is a better way to read the data with all the resources available in aws large instance.

Following is the code I am using right now.

```
def get_data(prefix_objs = prefix_objs, bucket = bucket, i = 0, prefix_df = [], cols = col):
    for obj in prefix_objs:
        i += 1
        key = obj.key
        file_path = 's3://' + bucket.name +'/'+str(key)
        temp = pd.read_csv(file_path,
                          sep = "|",
                          usecols = col)
        print("File No: {}".format(i))
        prefix_df.append(temp)
    return pd.concat(prefix_df)
```

Comment: What size (MB/GB) are the largest CSV files you're dealing with? And where does SageMaker come into this? Are you using it simply as a way to create a Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Use python **boto3** client or async version [aioboto3](https://github.com/terrycain/aioboto3) for downloading files from AWS S3

Comment: I have used the following code but its making my instance crash. "s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('test-bucket')
prefix_objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="files/splittedfiles/Code-345678")
for obj in prefix_objs:
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()"

Comment: What errors do you get? Make sure you have all the necessary credentials and have successfully connected to AWS from your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in SageMaker notebook instance or SageMaker training jobs (an async job)?
For training jobs see this [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/choose-the-best-data-source-for-your-amazon-sagemaker-training-job/).
For notebook instance, you might be better performance by copying all files locally first, using CLI command: `aws s3 sync s3://... /tmp`, then reading them from disk.

A side note - Try to switch P3->G5 instance - p3.2xlarge is a very old instance type. You will get better cost/efficiency and more GPU RAM with a g5 instance, plus g5 has local SSD drive, where p3.xlarge uses a slower EBS volume.